# Database Access Objects

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate

Is it good practice to do calculations and/or multiple queries within one call to your database object?

Generally in the past I've created a DAO and used it for purely just query calls. But now the opportunity has presented itself to do list concatenation from queries to potentially make my project more efficient.

So I was wondering if this is a good practice and if there are things I should watch out for and avoid to stay within the general standards of 'good' programming?

*And example of what I'm thinking about doing.*

Say I have and 'Execute' function in class 'A' which fires off and algorithm ->

this algorithm does various queries over certain scenarios calling to the DAO to return lists of and object from the database ->

Some of these scenarios may require more than 1 query ->

I'd hold in the DAO and execute these queries joining together lists of objects and return a single List to class 'A' as opposed to jumping back and forth between 'A' and my DAO.

Additional notes I'm going with and MVC setup with Hibernate/Spring

Comment: I would say that it is rather fine to do multiple non-heavy calculations within one opened `Connection`.

Comment: throwing in my 0.02c but, I'd be doing the heavy calculation operations in a service class method annotated `@Transactional`, and calling the DAO(s) as needed. I wouldn't be doing calculations or looping inside the DAO. A DAO should (as its name suggests) be concerned only with Data Access. It shouldn't care how you manipulate that data afterwards, its job it to only get you the data you want. Holding inside the DAO would be a bad idea, it will create a bottleneck, and database access is already a pretty significant bottleneck without you compounding the problem.